# Python: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 78: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

I've tried two variation in solving this problem yet will lead to another error. First by trying to `encode` and the other trying to `strip` (#) assuming that was the problem being caught in this error:

```
"color":rcolor,"text_color":tcolor})
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 78: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code is now looking like this:

```
routes = db.routes.find()
    for route in routes:
        try:
            color = route["properties"]["color"]
            color = color.strip('#')
            print(color)

            tcolor = route["properties"]["tcolor"]
            tcolor = tcolor.strip('#')
            print(tcolor)
        except KeyError:
            color = "0000FF"
            tcolor = ""

        writer.writerow({"route_id":route["route_id"],
                   "agency_id":route["properties"]["agency_id"],...,
                   "route_color":color,"route_text_color":tcolor})
```

I'm not quite sure anymore why it keeps getting the unicode error...

Comment: Please post a working example of the problem. This is very likely an issue with how you opened the file to write.

Comment: Any reason why you are using 2.7? Unicode support in python 3 is much better. 2.x is only useful when you have some legacy dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Try parsing your dict to have unicode values before writing to csv.

```
def convert(input):
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return {convert(key): convert(value) for key, value in input.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        return [convert(element) for element in input]
    elif isinstance(input, unicode):
        return input.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return input

if __name__ == "__main__":
    utf_route = convert(route)
```

So if you get the error while writing to csv please try the one below

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("local/file1.csv", "w", encoding='utf8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(data.keys())
    writer.writerow(data.values())
```

Comment: I tried to put it around this section yet the error still prevails... :                  for route in routes:
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                utf_route = convert(route)
            try:
                route_color = route["properties"]["route_color"]
                route_color = route_color.strip('#')
                print(route_color)

Comment: Is it possible for you to use `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` to dig the correct error location. I am not sure how long your input looks now.

Comment: let me try if I could. sorry it's my first project in python and I haven't really had the time to play around the debugger tool unlike in java

Comment: @Reiion That's ok. Don't use a for loop over the routes as per your first comment. You need to just pass the `routes` dictionary to `convert` method and the return will be a dictionary which will `utf-8` encoded. If you see there is a recursive call   `return {convert(key): convert(value) for key, value in input.iteritems()}` which takes care of that.

Comment: thank you for understanding. :) hmm well I did what you said. took `convert` just right after the mongodb query which is routes= db.routes.find and passed it like so: if __name__ == "__main__":
            utf_route = convert(routes). the same error occurs.

Comment: @Reiion Can you try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on top of your program. Also do you need those non-ascii values or is it fine to `strip` them.

Comment: sigh haha added and made a run, i still had the same error. and yes, that can be easily added back on read anyway if its needed. I just really have to solve this one problem. What's weird is, I tried printing out at least the dict values until where the error occurs and it will print without any problem. The error only occurs on csv write.

Comment: @Reiion Modified the answer. Can you take a look at the codec.open part where I am enforcing encoding while writing the csv.